# Pyside Import Error "No Module named Ctypes"

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, pyside, cryengine

Im pretty new to working with this side of python so pardon me if I'm a bit off kilter.

I am trying to incorporate `PySide` into Cryengine's Python 2.7.5 Integration; I used PIP to install the Site - Package to Cryengines Python Directory using the `pip install PySide.whl -t CRYENGINE/Editor/Python/Lib/Site - Package` command through command prompt.

Here is the script I am trying to run in the Python Shell Of CryEngine:

```
import sys
import site

site.ENABLE_USER_SITE
print site.USER_BASE
site.addsitedir("F:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\CRYENGINE\Editor\Python\Lib\site-packages\PySide")


from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

wid = QtGui.QWidget()
wid.resize(250, 150)
wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
wid.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the following error in the Python script terminal:

```
] from PySide import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 9, in _setupQtDirectories
    from . import _utils
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import ctypes
ImportError: No module named ctypes
```

I used pip to install the `PySide` wheel files. So its really weird that I am getting this error. I double checked the files that `ctypes` uses are there, and in the Python 2.7 installation. And all of them are there. I tested this using Python Shell, and it works great! But for some reason when I run it through CryEngine's python 2.7.5 integration even though the file path is to `C:\Python27` where all of those file Ctypes files are!

I am almost sure that I am oversimplifying the problem, but I'm not sure where to  start getting this problem solved. I want to get this working so I can build an integration that will work for the whole CryEngine Community. I've looked all over the place for a solution, but am really at the end of my rope here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Does Cry Engine's Python integration have `ctypes` in it? You might have to install that too. Also, you error refers to a local installation of Python, not some Python integration into Cry Engine, which makes things a bit confusing.